# Convert scraping result into an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, web-scraping

I am scraping a website using Simple HTML DOM, the output looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Satuan</th>
    <th>Harga Barang 1</th>
    <th>Harga Barang 2</th>
    <th>Harga Barang 3</th>
    <th>Harga Barang 4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>0.5</td>
    <td>Rp 388.000</td>
    <td>Rp 342.000</td>
    <td>Rp 456.000</td>
    <td>Rp 377.000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>Rp 725.000</td>
    <td>Rp 676.000</td>
    <td>Rp 855.000</td>
    <td>Rp 684.000</td>
</tr>
```

and this is my code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file("mylink.com/blabla");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

How to convert the output into arrays?

Comment: Access the text content (or whatever you are actually interested in) of the node inside the loop, and simply assign it as a new array element - where’s the actual _problem_? (FYI, you are _scraping_, not _scrapping_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet,

```
$ret     = $html->find('tr');
$i       = true;
$headers = [];
foreach ($ret as $key => $value) {
    if ($i) {
        // fetching headers of first row
        foreach ($value->find('th') as $cell) {
            $headers[] = $cell->plaintext;
        }
    } else {
        $temp = [];
        // fetching pending values of td
        foreach ($value->find('td') as $cell) {
            $temp[] = $cell->plaintext;
        }
        // combining headers with values fetched from not first row
        $result[] = array_combine($headers, $temp);
    }
    $i = false;
}
print_r($result);die;
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Satuan] => 0.5
            [Harga Barang 1] => Rp 388.000
            [Harga Barang 2] => Rp 342.000
            [Harga Barang 3] => Rp 456.000
            [Harga Barang 4] => Rp 377.000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Satuan] => 1.0
            [Harga Barang 1] => Rp 725.000
            [Harga Barang 2] => Rp 676.000
            [Harga Barang 3] => Rp 855.000
            [Harga Barang 4] => Rp 684.000
        )

)
```